# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android, kotlin

Just upgraded the IDE and started to sync the gradle but IDE throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve it is

```
Go to Help and about to see your android studio version
go to File>Project Structure> and set your Android Gradle Plugin version to your android studio version
Change the Gradle version to the one you usually use.
```

If that does not work do this

```
id 'com.android.application' version '7.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21' apply false
```

Answer (score 0):

If still, the error persists then find the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and change it to compatible version :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

change `7.2` to your Gradle version